# PHP DOMNode : how to extract not only text but HTML tags also

Tags: php, dom, screen-scraping

I'm trying to make a script that scrapes a website to retrieve the latest news updates.
Unfortunately I've run into a small issue that I can't seem to fix with my limited knowledge of DOM.

The page I'm trying to scrape is built as follows :

> ```
> <table>
> <tr class="color1">
> <td>Author</td>
> <td>Content <a href="#">in HTML</a></td>
> <td>Date</td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

I can retrieve the fields I need just fine, except for content. With $td->nodeValue I retrieve the content in text form, whereas I want it in HTML (there's 'a' tags in there, 'blockquote', etc)

Here's the code I have :

```
try {
    $html = @ file_get_contents("test.php");
    checkIfFileExists($html);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @ $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $trNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tr");
    foreach ($trNodes as $tr) {

        if ($tr->getAttribute("class") == "color1" || $tr->getAttribute("class") == "color2") {

        $tdNodes = $tr->childNodes;
        foreach ($tdNodes as $td) {

            echo $td->nodeValue . "<br />\n";

        }
        echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />\n";
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I would prefer not to have to resort to any third party library, but obviously any answer is most appreciated, library or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
echo $td->nodeValue . "<br />\n";
```

with

```
echo $dom->saveXML($td)  . "<br />\n";
```